# how to run different scrapy projects in just one python scripts

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

all. I am new to Scrapy and meet some difficulties trying to call multiple spider projects in a same script. I have three Scrapy projects which separately crawl different webpages and store the data into SQLite. But I cannot figure out how to manage the projects with one single Python scripts. Here is what I tried:
 1. I see from the official documentation using CrawlerProcess, but this code can't store data into SQLite with pipeline. 
Here is the example code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your first spider definition
    ...

class MySpider2(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your second spider definition
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(MySpider1)
process.crawl(MySpider2)
process.start() # the script will block here until all crawling jobs are finished
```

2.I used three scripts to call

```
os.system("scrapy crawl myspider")
```

and used a overall script to import these three scripts, but the error comes like that:

```
Unknown Command:crawl
Use "scrapy" to see available commands
```

Now my problem is, how to call the three different projects in just one python scripts, without using "scrapy crawl XXX". I am really confused.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where does _"but this code can't store data into SQLite with pipeline"_ come from? have you enabled your pipelines in the script?

Comment: I just enabled them in the setting.py, and don't know how to enable them in the script. It seems difficult to achieve all the scraping works in a script file. Now I find the most effective way to run multiple spider projects is using Scrapyd. Thanks for reply:-D

Answer (score 0):

Scrapyd is used to run multiple spider projects. But there is a small problem. The spider projects must be stopped in the command line, while I want to stop the spiders in my script.